# rock paper scissors kattis: Test Cases

Tags: java

Hi I have been looking everywhere, to determine what is considered undefined as specified in : https://open.kattis.com/problems/rockpaperscissors

I pass the first test, but keep failing the second. I originally thought I failed the second test because I only allowed two players in total which we have to allow multiple players to join in.

I fixed this issue, but still fail second test.

I put in what I consider to be undefined but am completely stuck.

So Question: Can someone provide me a test case that will lead me in the right direction?

I am not asking for the code but a test case, If you do notice something I have typed in wrong on my code please do inform if this is what is causing my issue.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class RockPaperScissor {
/**Conditions******
  *
*/
 public static void main(String[] args) {
   /************User Input************/
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     /*************Variables***************/

     String Player1;
     String Player2;
     String game="";
     String playerGame=sc.nextLine();
    //System.out.println("PlayerA= " +numOfGames);


//System.out.println(game);
/**run through games until game=0;**/
do{


    String[] playerGameSplit = playerGame.split("\\s+");
    int numOfPlayers=Integer.parseInt(playerGameSplit[0]);
    double numOfGames=(Integer.parseInt(playerGameSplit[1])*numOfPlayers*(numOfPlayers-1))/2;
//  double player1Win=0, player2Win=0, player1Loss=0, player2Loss=0;
    Integer[] player = new Integer[numOfPlayers];
    Integer[] playerLoss = new Integer[numOfPlayers];
    for(int x=0; x<player.length;x++){
        player[x]=0;
        playerLoss[x]=0;
    }
    /*****Runs Rock Paper Scissors Game*****/
    for (int x = 0; x<numOfGames; x++) {
        /**Starts first game**/
        game=sc.nextLine();
        String[] splitter = game.split("\\s+");
        if(compare(splitter[1],splitter[3])==1){
                player[Integer.parseInt(splitter[0])-1]=player[Integer.parseInt(splitter[0])-1]+1;
            playerLoss[Integer.parseInt(splitter[2])-1]=playerLoss[Integer.parseInt(splitter[2])-1]+1;
        }else if(compare(splitter[1],splitter[3])==-1){
            player[Integer.parseInt(splitter[2])-1]=player[Integer.parseInt(splitter[2])-1]+1;
            playerLoss[Integer.parseInt(splitter[0])-1]=playerLoss[Integer.parseInt(splitter[0])-1]+1;
        }
    } 

                /***Prints Required OutPut***/
    for(int x=0; x<player.length;x++){


        //if(player[x]==0&&playerLoss[x]==0){
            ////double ratio= player[x]/(player[x]+playerLoss[x]);
            //System.out.println("-");
        //}else
        if(Double.isInfinite((double)player[x]/(double)(player[x]+playerLoss[x]))){
            //double ratio= player[x]/(player[x]+playerLoss[x]);
            System.out.println("-");
        }else if(Double.isNaN((double)player[x]/(double)(player[x]+playerLoss[x]))){
            System.out.println("-");
        }else{
            double ratio= (double)player[x]/(double)(player[x]+playerLoss[x]);
        System.out.printf("%.3f", ratio);
        System.out.println();
        }
    }

    System.out.println();
    /**moves Game to next one**/
    playerGame=sc.nextLine();


  }while(playerGame.matches("[\\d][\\s][\\d]"));
    //System.out.println("do we make here");    
     }

                 /*********METHODS*******/
     public static Integer compare(String Player1,String Player2){
    //System.out.println(Player1+ " "+ Player2);
    if(Player1.matches("rock")&&Player2.matches("scissors")){
    return 1;
  }else
 if(Player2.matches("rock")&&Player1.matches("scissors")){
    return -1;
 }else
 if(Player1.matches("paper")&&Player2.matches("rock")){
    return 1;
}else
if(Player2.matches("paper")&&Player1.matches("rock")){
   return -1;
 }else
if(Player1.matches("scissors")&&Player2.matches("paper")){
   return 1;   
 }else
 if(Player2.matches("scissors")&&Player1.matches("paper")){
   return -1;
   }else
      return 0;

  }
 }

    /***********Sample Input*************/

  /**
  2 4
 1 rock 2 paper
 1 scissors 2 paper
 1 rock 2 rock
 2 rock 1 scissors
 2 1
 1 rock 2 paper
 3 1
 1 rock 2 paper
 3 rock 2 paper
 1 rock 3 paper
 0
 **/

 /***********Sample Output*************/
 /**
 0.333
 0.667

 0.000
 1.000
 **/
```

Comment: Do you have any test cases written so far? Also, to make testing easier, try to use more functions. For example, you could have a function which parses the playerGameSplit and sets the 2 variables "numOfPlayers" and "numOfGames." Then you can easily test that function and determine if that section of your code is working correctly, before moving onto the next part.

Comment: Is there a law that these online code submissions never use objects?  I've yet to see many (beyond myself) that bother to model the Player or the Round or the Tournament.  If you did these things, player averages would be trivial to calculate.

Comment: @EdwinBuck

Okay I did what you said but still coming up short, so if you might look at my new code and let me know what you think.

Comment: @PunDefeated

Yes and No, They are inside a for loop, however, I have tested each section before moving onto the next.

Answer (score 1):

Now that you have a Player, you can unit test the player.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Assert;

public class PlayerTest {

   @Test
   public void newPlayerRatio() {
     try {
       Player player = new Player();
       Assert.assertEquals(0.0d, player.getWinRatio(), 0.001d);
     } catch (Exception e) {
       Assert.fail(String.format("Unexpected Exception thrown of type %s", e.getClass()));
     }
}
```

Testing parts of your code can only be done when you isolate parts of your code.  That's why I asked for the classes, they encapsulate something.  That encapsulation means that they contain some behavior.  Once part of your program contains (is solely responsible) for some behavior, it becomes easy to test.

Due to my experience, I can state that you are going to find an unexpected result in the test above; because, you don't check to see if you would divide by zero before you do.

Write a few extra unit tests (testing with win ratio of a player with one win, one win and one loss, etc).  After you have half a dozen, move on to the next part of your code.

Eventually you will have some sort or reader which takes a line of input and updates the tournament.  Once you get to that part, you can experiment with feeding it a line of code an seeing if it calls the "right" methods with the "right" values in the Tournament.  Odds are that there is some corner case that's killing your program.

Once you have your battery of tests, any changes that break the assumptions about what the units of code do will make the tests fail immediately.  To this end, I suggest you look into Apache's Maven (or something like it) to automate the running of tests with your build (or at least look into your IDE to see how to run the tests with every code change).

Comment: Well I have never used Junit before, this looks very beneficial, thank you for providing your insight. I am going work on this and see what I find.